# Flutter built iOS app not starting in production

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store

I have a flutter app that is building and working perfectly well on both my iOS simulator and my physical iPhone when I run it from Xcode or Android Studio.

Now I published it to the AppStore, and after a couple of users that have downloaded it, the app isn't even starting for them.. it crashes even before reaching the splash screen.

I tried to add Crashlytics in order to catch an error if there's any but nothing was reported.

Did any of you face a similar issue ? Is there a way to understand what's happening ?

Here's my main.dart file:

```
import 'package:animated_theme_switcher/animated_theme_switcher.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_crashlytics/firebase_crashlytics.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:tupitools/core/locator.dart';
import 'package:tupitools/core/models/expansion_torque_search_model.dart';
import 'package:tupitools/core/models/gauge_converter_search_model.dart';
import 'package:tupitools/core/models/gauge_tube_chart_search_model.dart';
import 'package:tupitools/core/models/nominal_pipe_size_search_model.dart';
import 'package:tupitools/core/models/tes2_search_model.dart';
import 'package:tupitools/core/models/tube_expansion_search_model.dart';
import 'package:tupitools/core/theme_service.dart';
import 'package:tupitools/screens/splashscreen.dart';
import 'package:tupitools/utils/sp_utils.dart';

import 'firebase_options.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
  await SPUtil.init();
  await ScreenUtil.ensureScreenSize();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  FlutterError.onError = (errorDetails) {
    FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError(errorDetails);
  };
  // Pass all uncaught asynchronous errors that aren't handled by the Flutter framework to Crashlytics
  PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError = (error, stack) {
    FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stack, fatal: true);
    return true;
  };

  final themeService = await ThemeService.instance;
  var initTheme = themeService.initial;
  await setupLocator();
  final document = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  await Hive.initFlutter(document.path);
  Hive.registerAdapter(GaugeTubeChartSearchModelAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(GaugeConverterSearchModelAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(NominalPipeSizeSearchModelAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(TubeExpansionSearchModelAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(ExpansionTorqueSearchModelAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(TES2SearchModelAdapter());

  if (!SPUtil.containsKey(SPUtil.keyConvertersOrder)) {
    SPUtil.setStringList(SPUtil.keyConvertersOrder, ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]);
  }

  if (!SPUtil.containsKey(SPUtil.keyConvertersOrderByName)) {
    SPUtil.setStringList(SPUtil.keyConvertersOrderByName,
        ['Length', 'Weight', 'Circumference to diameter', 'Torque', 'Power', 'Flow rate']);
  }

  runApp(MyApp(theme: initTheme));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final ThemeData theme;

  const MyApp({super.key, required this.theme});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark, // iOS
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, // Android
    ));
    final mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    final scale = mediaQueryData.textScaleFactor.clamp(1.0, 1.0);
    return MediaQuery(
      data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: scale),
      child: ScreenUtilInit(
        useInheritedMediaQuery: true,
        designSize: const Size(393, 852),
        minTextAdapt: true,
        builder: (context, child) {
          return ThemeProvider(
            initTheme: theme,
            builder: (_, theme) {
              return MaterialApp(
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                title: 'App name',
                theme: theme,
                home: child,
              );
            },
          );
        },
        child: const SplashScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to run the app in release mode?

Comment: can you provide your main.dart file?

Comment: @AbhishekKarad I tired in release mode and it worked fine on my iPhone SE

Comment: @lucie I updated my post and added the main.dart file

Comment: If nothing is logged on Crashlytics, it can mean that the error arrived sooner. For instance, what happens if you call SPUtil.init() after the firebase and crashlytics initialization ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I updated flutter SDK and all the dependencies to the latest version, and everything is working fine since. Not sure what was causing the issue in the first place though ..